# Bean life cycle - afterPropertiesSet()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create `CustomWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter` which extends `org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter`.

`WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter` extends abstract `WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport`which implements `InitializingBean`.

I have a problem, because I don’t understand why I have to call
`afterPropertiesSet()` in custom handler. I get an error without calling this method: “factory message is required”. But, this method is calling in abstract class, so my custom handler should run `afterPropertiesSet()` from abstract class. If you know the solution, let me know. Thanks a lot.

edit: This is my `CustomWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter` :

```
public class CustomWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter extends WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter {

@Override
protected void handleInvalidXmlException(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object handler,
        InvalidXmlException ex) throws Exception {
    //code
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() {

}
}
```

`WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter` and `WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport` are from Spring Framework

```
public class WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter extends WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport{}
```

There is no `afterPropertiesSet()`

```
public abstract class WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport implements InitializingBean {

    private WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory;

    /** Returns the {@code WebServiceMessageFactory}. */
    public WebServiceMessageFactory getMessageFactory() {
        return messageFactory;
    }

    /** Sets the {@code WebServiceMessageFactory}. */
    public void setMessageFactory(WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory) {
        this.messageFactory = messageFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(messageFactory, "messageFactory is required");
    }
```

And now, when I am removing `afterPropertiesSet()` from my custom handler an exception is thrown. In my opinion, I don't understand something about life cycle of bean.

Comment: I think you need to add some code to clarify your problem.

Comment: Ok, give me a moment :D

Comment: The exceptin is thrown because you don't set that property, hence the exception. This has nothing to do with the lifecycle.

Comment: but afterPropertSet() is not inherited from the abstract class ?

Comment: Yes it is and it is called, hence the exception. I fyou override it with an empty one it doesn't do anything, but that still doesn't fix your issue you still aren't setting the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about your specific case. In general if a bean implements `InitializingBean` and thus the `afterPropertiesSet` this method is called after instantiation of the bean instance and after Spring injected all `@Autowired` properties/values.

In your specific case you need to ensure that `messageFactory` property of your (via inheritance) class is set. Typically this is done by Spring, if you provide a suitable setter for autowiring:

```
@Autowired
@Override
public void setMessageFactory(WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory) {
  super.setMessageFactory(messageFactory);
}
```

If you overrride `afterPropertiesSet` without calling `super.afterPropertiesSet()` creation of the bean will work as the assertion of the super implementation is skipped. But you will likely encounter problems further down the line as the `messageFactory` property is not properly initialized.